# Hide and show forms after press a button HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a kind of calculator of economic status, using two separated forms in the same web page, but hiding the second one.

What I need is a way to do this, how to "move" the first form away of screen and show the second one after pressing a button and also show the results in the same way. Honestly I have no idea of how to search for that so I ended here.

Also, what would you recomend me to use with this, only Javascript? thaking in mind that there is no users or any kind of storage besides the data obteined from the form.

Comment: Add you code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding/showing HTML forms (on button press) using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840700/hiding-showing-html-forms-on-button-press-using-javascript)

Comment: Is not a duplicate...I have no code because it's a fresh start, I'm here because I have no idea of how to make the thing that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use angularJS (ngShow ngHide) or use a new state

Comment: Don't you think that's a little overkill to bring up a whole development environment, when a simple `form1.style.display='none'; form2.style.display='block';` would do the trick?